# Data validation routine not working

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling

I have this macro which checks for blanks from A cell to I. If the cells are blank the user isn't able to save. But the problem is that if I dont enter anything in the A cell then save is enabled.

Here's my VBA code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rsave As Range, N As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    With Sheet2
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To N
            Set rsave = Range("A" & i & ":I" & i)
            For Each cell In rsave
                If cell = "" Then
                    Dim missdata
                    missdata = MsgBox("missing data", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data")
                    Cancel = True
                    cell.Select
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next cell
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through the code to see why it enables save?

Comment: [Check this out to improve your coding and where my post below is based](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just correctly reference the objects you are working on.
For example, you use `With Statement` in this line but the next line isn't really referenced to `Sheet2`.

```
With Sheet2
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

To correctly reference the properties and objects, precede it with a `dot` like:

```
With Sheet2
    N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'notice the dot before Cells
```

Same goes with this line: `Set rsave = Range("A" & i & ":I" & i)`
It should be:

```
Set rsave = .Range("A" & i & ":I" & i) 'notice the dot
```

Now instead of doing a nested loop, you can do it with one. 
Also, reference your last row relative to the entire column. Try below code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rsave As Range, N As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    With Sheet2
        N = .Range("A:I").Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        Set rsave = .Range("A1:I" & N)
        For Each cell In rsave
            If cell = "" Then
                MsgBox "Missing data.", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data"
                Cancel = True
                cell.Select
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

You see, `cell` variable iterate from left to right, up down.
So it checks A1, B1, C1.. etc then A2, B2, C2... HTH.